# Tab no longer returns to root of tab when in child component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

We have been using an old version of Material UI for some time now and we noticed after upgrading to the latest one the behaviour of the tabs have changed.

Previously, if you had child components within a page, the tab would keep the correct underline. And when you clicked on the selected tab, it would rerender to the tabs url, causing the user to navigate back to the page the tab is directed at.

After the upgrade we noticed that if the tab is underlined and you select it, the onChange method is not called and so the user is not navigated back to the url on the tab.

Are there any properties that can be set which forces the previous behaviour to happen? Or is it possible we are using the tabs incorrectly in the first place?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have fixed this by adding onClick to the tabs with nested components.